Error When Using unstructured to Partition PDF Files
I'm trying to use the unstructured, unstructured[pdf] library in Python to partition a .pdf file, but I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve. The pdf file contains text, table, image,...
Here's a brief overview of what I'm doing:
from unstructured.partition.pdf import partition_pdf

path = '/content/'
file_name = 'ABCABC.pdf'

raw_pdf_elements = partition_pdf(
    filename=path + file_name,
    extract_images_in_pdf=True,
    infer_table_structure=True,
    chunking_strategy="by_title",
    max_characters=4000,
    new_after_n_chars=3800,
    combine_text_under_n_chars=2000,
    image_output_dir_path=path
)

Error Message:
When I run the code, I get the following error:
NameError: name 'sort_page_elements' is not defined

Environment:

python: 3.9.19
unstructured: 0.15.1 (I also tried 0.7.12 and 0.12.2 )
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Question:
What could be causing this NameError, and how can I resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Update
I have tried solution @Oluwafemi Sule, but it doesn't work, my environment has both numpy and opencv-python

numpy: 1.26.4
opencv-python (cv2):4.10.0.84

I have to deactivate the environment and activate again, but I'm encountering an another error.
get_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ocr_languages'


Solution:

I add a addition parameter for partition_pdf: for example: languages=["vie"]
I need download the trained data for specified languages in here
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=Path_of_your_tessdata_folder (the folder that contain the file is downloaded step 2)


You have a NameError because partition_pdf calls the document_to_element_list function and it calls sort_page_elements
sort_page_elements is only imported in the module when the numpy and cv2 libraries to be available.
You should install numpy and cv2

Thanks, how should you find unstructured/partition/common.py from my message. I means the way you search.

Search for sort_page_elements in the project and look up references to it.

I have checked on my environment, numpy and cv2 are available, however, it's not work
